# Oculus Rift cannot display with Macbook

Tags: macos, oculus, virtual-reality

I have an issue with running Oculus DK 2 on Macbook, the latest version Oculus runtime. The issue is that I cannot change the display mode in settings, it is disabled. Therefore, when I run the demo scene, it is only display on the main desktop, nothing on Oculus Rift display. Please help!!! 
Please see this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8WtbdbX1xQiZGx4dHc0QmttQk0/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct to rift is not supported on OSX. Rift works only as a second screen. For a quick howto on how to setup the screen look at http://mozvr.com/downloads/

Also, note that oculus on OSX is not supported for some time now, and things like firmware update on windows might break support on OSX.